# Jquery validation plugin require_from_group function issue

Tags: jquery, validation

I am validating a from using Jquery Validation Plugin (latest version 1.11).
I have my form and fields setup like this,

***Form***
                
                
                
                
                
                Recipe Title:<sup>*</sup>

```
            <div class="row control-group">
            <label for="recipecats" class="col col-lg-2 control-label">Recipe Category:<sup>&#42;</sup></label>
            <div class="col col-lg-3 controls">
            <select class="input-with-feedback recicat" id="recipecats" name="recipecats" title="Please select a category">
            <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr(__('Select Category')); ?></option> 
            <?php   $categories=  get_categories('child_of=47'); foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category->slug;?>"><?php echo $category->cat_name;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>

            <label for="recipecatssug" class="col col-lg-2 control-label">Suggested:<sup>&nbsp;</sup></label>
            <div class="col col-lg-2 controls">
            <input id="recipecatssug" class="input-with-feedback recicat" data-content="Optional: You may suggest a category if its not listed." data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" title="Suggested Category" name="recipecatssug" placeholder="Suggest Cat" type="text">
            </div>
            </div> <!-- recipe cats -->


            <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-lg-10 col-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </div>

            </form>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div> <!-- recipe-form -->
```

***Validation***

```
                        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#recipe-submit-form').validate({
            rules: {
            recipetitle: {
            minlength: 10,
            required: true
            },

            groups: {
            name: "recipecats recipecatssug"
            },
            recipecats: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".recicat"]
            },
            recipecatssug: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".recicat"]
            }
            },

            messages: {
            recipetitle: {
            required: "Pleae enter a valid recipe title",
            minlength: "Recipe title must be at least 8 characters long"
            },
            recipecats: { 
            require_from_group: "Pleae select at-least one category or suggest a custom"
            }
            },
            });
            }); // end document.ready
</script>
```

Problem here is, when the form is validated, it only validates last fields (Category & Suggested Cat) other fields error are not shown and focus is not shifted to first input field.
and assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I don't see `<form id='recipe-submit-form'>`. Do you perhaps have it and forgot to paste it here?

Comment: Also I couldn't see element `recipetitle` and `groups`. Could you paste the complete form?

Comment: Hi Erdo, just assume these details are there, except group which is part of jquery validation plugin. my main concern is to identify the prob.

Comment: Hi. That's the problem: validation is not works on other fields except category and suggested category. Thats why that other fields are needed to indentify the prob.